# How to check continuously and see if an elements specific style has changed and to perform actions based on that change

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, navbar

So currently I have made a nav menu for my site. When at desktop size it displays the nav list items left to right visible with no action needed, and when screen is shrunk past the cutoff the items disappear, a hamburger button replaces them, and clicking that slides a box from the right that takes up the whole height and width containing the list items and a close button and it also adds a class that disables scrolling, you click the close button and the box retracts back to the right and removes the class preventing the scrolling.

Pretty simple, the problem is it has the issue of when the menu is opened at smaller screen size and not closed, then resized up it disappears which is what I want but it also keeps the no scroll, but if you then size it back down, the menu is already open because the class was never removed. I've provided my code down below to replicate my menu and the issue.

What I am basically after is a way to remove the classes for an open menu when the screen sizes back up past the cutoff, just like the close button does when removing the classes.

HTML

```
<header class="main-header">
        <img class="business-logo-header" src="images\icons\business-logo-header.svg" alt="Logo" width="320" height="51" decoding="async">
        <button class="nav-open-btn" type="button">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="4 6 16 12">
          <g id="Menu / Hamburger_MD">
          <path class="nav-open-path" d="M5 17H19M5 12H19M5 7H19" stroke="#0d4c92" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
          </g>
          </svg>
        </button>
        <nav class="main-nav">
          <ul class="main-nav-list">
            <button class="nav-close-btn" type="button">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="5 5 14 14">
                <g id="Menu / Close_MD">
                <path class="nav-close-path" id="Vector" d="M18 18L12 12M12 12L6 6M12 12L18 6M12 12L6 18" stroke="#0d4c92" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                </g>
                </svg>
            </button>
            <li><a class="list-item" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="list-item" href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a class="list-item" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a class="list-item" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.business-logo-header {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 32rem;
  height: auto;
}

.nav-open-btn {
  width: 15%;
  max-width: 6.8rem;
  margin: 1.25rem 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-open-path,
.nav-close-path {
  transition: stroke 200ms;
}

.nav-open-btn:hover .nav-open-path {
  stroke: #59c1bd;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 250ms;
}

.main-nav-open {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-close-btn {
  width: clamp(5rem, 3.79vw + 3.79rem, 7.5rem);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: clamp(0.75rem, 0.76vw + 0.51rem, 1.25rem);
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-close-btn:hover .nav-close-path {
  stroke: #59c1bd;
}

.main-nav-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-item:link,
.list-item:visited {
  display: block;
  margin: clamp(0.75rem, 0.76vw + 0.51rem, 1.25rem);
  font-size: clamp(3.6rem, 2.42vw + 2.82rem, 5.2rem);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0d4c92;
  transition: color 200ms;
}

.list-item:hover,
.list-item:active {
  color: #59c1bd;
}

@media (min-width: 980px) {
  /* NAVIGATION */
  .nav-open-btn {
    display: none;
  }

  .main-nav {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: static;
    z-index: 0;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
  }

  .main-nav-open {
    width: auto;
  }

  .nav-close-btn {
    display: none;
  }

  .main-nav-list {
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
    align-items: normal;
  }

  .list-item:link,
  .list-item:visited {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
```

Javascript

```
const navOpenBTN = document.querySelector(".nav-open-btn");
const navCloseBTN = document.querySelector(".nav-close-btn");
const mainNav = document.querySelector(".main-nav");

navOpenBTN.addEventListener("click", () => {
  mainNav.classList.add("main-nav-open");
  document.body.classList.add("stop-scrolling");
});

navCloseBTN.addEventListener("click", () => {
  mainNav.classList.remove("main-nav-open");
  document.body.classList.remove("stop-scrolling");
});
```

Someone suggested me to use a `window.addEventListener("resize", ())` and detect if it reaches that window width cutoff, for it to look and see if the nav menu contains the class that has it open and if so for it to remove it and the no scroll one as well. I've never actually used a resize event listener before, which led me to research into it.

I'm not sure if this would be a good option for performance because it seems that this will be constantly checking every time the screen size is changed and could lag the site from what I've read, there's ways of circumventing it with throttling, and debouncing but then it wouldn't happen exactly when you reach the cut-off but only when the timer has told it to check again? which means there would be a moment where you're not gonna be able to scroll the page because it hasn't checked yet and removed the classes. I could be wrong on this thought process and if so I would love some clarifications.

Then I learned about a mutationObserver which I think may be a better approach if I can even figure it out. I've used intersectionObserver before for adding animation classes to elements when they come into view but it seems like the syntax for the mutationObserver is much more complex.

What I am thinking is using a mutation observer on the hamburger button to detect a style change from display block to display none, and if it is display none, and the navmenu contains the class for open then remove it and the no scroll class from the body.

I think this should work but what I can't seem to find anywhere is how to just observe a specific style attribute like the "Display" to see if anything has changed with it and if so run the function checking the navMenu for the open class.

Most examples I've seen, appear to show people just checking for any changes at all to an element or to its children which is not what I am wanting. I just can't seem to find any good articles or videos that show how to observe a specific style attribute change, I don't even know if its possible but I thought I would come here and ask as a last resort.

Any info would be helpful, whether I'm wrong about the resize event listener and it would be the best approach or an explanation on how to observe a specific style attribute on an element with mutationObserver

Answer (score 0):

You could simply trigger a click on the close button whenever the window is resized with:

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", () => navCloseBTN.dispatchEvent(new Event("click")));
```

```js
const navOpenBTN = document.querySelector(".nav-open-btn");
const navCloseBTN = document.querySelector(".nav-close-btn");
const mainNav = document.querySelector(".main-nav");

navOpenBTN.addEventListener("click", () => {
  mainNav.classList.add("main-nav-open");
  document.body.classList.add("stop-scrolling");
});

navCloseBTN.addEventListener("click", () => {
  mainNav.classList.remove("main-nav-open");
  document.body.classList.remove("stop-scrolling");
});

window.addEventListener("resize", () => navCloseBTN.dispatchEvent(new Event("click")));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 3rem;
}

.business-logo-header {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 32rem;
  height: auto;
}

.nav-open-btn {
  width: 15%;
  max-width: 6.8rem;
  margin: 1.25rem 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-open-path,
.nav-close-path {
  transition: stroke 200ms;
}

.nav-open-btn:hover .nav-open-path {
  stroke: #59c1bd;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 250ms;
}

.main-nav-open {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-close-btn {
  width: clamp(5rem, 3.79vw + 3.79rem, 7.5rem);
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: clamp(0.75rem, 0.76vw + 0.51rem, 1.25rem);
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-close-btn:hover .nav-close-path {
  stroke: #59c1bd;
}

.main-nav-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-item:link,
.list-item:visited {
  display: block;
  margin: clamp(0.75rem, 0.76vw + 0.51rem, 1.25rem);
  font-size: clamp(3.6rem, 2.42vw + 2.82rem, 5.2rem);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0d4c92;
  transition: color 200ms;
}

.list-item:hover,
.list-item:active {
  color: #59c1bd;
}

@media (min-width: 980px) {
  /* NAVIGATION */
  .nav-open-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-nav {
    background-color: transparent;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: static;
    z-index: 0;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
  }
  .main-nav-open {
    width: auto;
  }
  .nav-close-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-nav-list {
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
    align-items: normal;
  }
  .list-item:link,
  .list-item:visited {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <img class="business-logo-header" src="images\icons\business-logo-header.svg" alt="Logo" width="320" height="51" decoding="async">
  <button class="nav-open-btn" type="button">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="4 6 16 12">
          <g id="Menu / Hamburger_MD">
          <path class="nav-open-path" d="M5 17H19M5 12H19M5 7H19" stroke="#0d4c92" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
          </g>
          </svg>
        </button>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav-list">
      <button class="nav-close-btn" type="button">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="5 5 14 14">
                <g id="Menu / Close_MD">
                <path class="nav-close-path" id="Vector" d="M18 18L12 12M12 12L6 6M12 12L18 6M12 12L6 18" stroke="#0d4c92" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                </g>
                </svg>
            </button>
      <li><a class="list-item" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="list-item" href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a class="list-item" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a class="list-item" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Well that seems nice but again like I stated in my question wouldn't there still be a problem with the resize being checked constantly whenever the window is resized, causing lag and performance trouble